Problemas de conectividad Win11 e Xiaomi Hyperos
Estoy buscando soluciones para conectar mi dispositivo (Xiaomi 12T- HYPEROS) a mi computadora (Hp - Win11).
El problema es que tengo activada la depuración USB e inalámbrica, todos mis drivers actualizados, cable USB original, etc. He hecho la mayor parte de lo que aconsejan las soluciones comunes, todavía no se conecta. Pero si el PC lo detecta cargarlo y nada más (incluso teniendo activada la transferencia de archivos)
Específicamente es para usar mi dispositivo como emulador físico con código VS y fluter, ejecuté flutter doctor y todo está bien. Adjunto imágenes, agradecería su apoyo!!



Finalmente no es problema del teléfono, es del ordenador, ya que he probado con otro teléfono Android y sigue sin conectarse.
